# Export MySql Data to excel sheet in asp.net mvc

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a secure Mysql database i need to export it in excel sheet, i try it to export normal data as in the ProductModel and its working, all i need now is to update the code to export from Mysql database.
you will find the controller, view, ProductModel and Product;
controller :

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        ViewBag.listProducts = pm.findAll(); 
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Export()
    {
        try
        {

            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "id";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Price";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Quantity";
            int row = 2;
            foreach (Product p in pm.findAll())
            {

                worksheet.Cells[row, 1] = p.id;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 2] = p.Name;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 3] = p.Price;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 4] = p.Quantity;


               row++;

            }

            worksheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            workbook.SaveAs("d:\\test\\myproduct.xls");
            workbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);

            ViewBag.Result = "Done";

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ViewBag.Result = ex.Message;
        }
        return View("Success");
    }
}
```

ProductModel:

```
public class ProductModel
{

    public List<Product> findAll()
    {
        List<Product> listProducts= new List<Product>();
        listProducts.Add(new Product { id="p01",Name="MichtiDao",Price=1000,Quantity = 6,DateCreation =new DateTime (2016,07,10) });
        listProducts.Add(new Product { id = "p02", Name = "zellabi", Price = 2000, Quantity = 55, DateCreation = new DateTime(2016, 07, 11) });
        listProducts.Add(new Product { id = "p03", Name = "Banana", Price = 3000, Quantity = 150, DateCreation = DateTime.Now });
        listProducts.Add(new Product { id = "p04", Name = "Penapple", Price = 4000, Quantity = 250, DateCreation = DateTime.Now });

        return listProducts;
     }

}
```

Product:

```
 public class Product
{

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }

}
```

View :

```
<body>
```

#### List Product

```
    <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>quantity</th>


    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var p in ViewBag.listProducts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@p.id</td>
                <td>@p.Name</td>
                <td>@p.Price</td>
                <td>@p.Quantity</td>

            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>


    </table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
    <a href="@Url.Action("export","Product")">Export</a>
```

Comment: So, what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: ok i tried to export data to excel and i did it well .

Comment: Now i need  to export the data from Mysql database to excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your product table name is `Tbl_Product` and your database entity name is `DatabaseEntity`, so you can change `findAll()` metod like below to export from your sql database:

```
public class ProductModel
{

    public IEnumerable<Tbl_Product> findAll()
    {
       var _databaseEntity = new DatabaseEntity(); 
       var products = from prod in _databaseEntity.Tbl_Product
                       select prod;


        return products ;
     }

}
```